# What "reachability" means in a routing table?

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, ios

Check this routing table

```
track 1 ip route 10.46.52.5 255.255.255.255 reachability
ip route 10.1.0.0 255.255.128.0 10.243.222.1 track 1
ip route 10.1.128.0 255.255.128.0 10.243.222.1 track 1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.11.70.2 name FW_INTERNET
ip route 10.1.3.211 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/0.10 tag 20
ip route 10.1.5.1 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/0.10 tag 20
```

In the first route what does **reachability** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just checking connectivity...

Answer (score 3):

`reachability` is not part of the routing table, but of an object tracking instruction. It checks whether the route is reachable ([see here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t15/feature/guide/fthsrptk.html)).

Comment: What does it mean? If is available send the packets go through there?

Comment: It will not send any packets. It will simply check if it is in the routing table and if its next hop is also reachable.

Comment: A why is it checked? If this next hop is available what decision does it takes? or is simply for logging? Thank you @Oliver

Comment: It could be for logging, but also for other actions like, for example, activating a secondary interface.

Comment: in this case only make a check or where is the action?

Comment: The answer to this question lies in the configuration of the router...